# number of pattern matching attempt in android 2.3(Maxx msd7)

Tags: factory-reset

When i start my phone(Maxx msd7),i am getting "number of invalid pattern matching attempts" error in android 2.3.I am trying to perform factory reset at starup.

I got the recovery menu at startup by pressing volume - button but i am not getting Factory reset option over there.

- TEST ITEM
- TEST ALL
- CLEAR FLASH

options are there.

What should i do.?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more details about the error. Exactly when does the error message appear? What does it look like? What is the *exact* message?

Answer (score 0):

Solved....

Select clear flash option,It will restart phone and menu will be displayed at startup.

Comment: Good work. If you want this information to be useful to future visitors, you should edit your question to say what phone these are the instructions for. Not every Android phone has the same recovery menu.